# Is it possible to force JList to a fixed size

Tags: java, swing

I know I could set the minimum and maximum dimensions to prevent the JList from resizing but I was wondering if anything like `JList.setFixed(true)` or something similar exists?

The reason for me not using the max and min dimensions is that they currently appear as 0,0 0,0 and I don't wish to spend time using trial and error to find my perfect size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use:

```
list.setVisibleRowCount(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
panel.add( scrollPane );
```

The panel should use a layout manager that respects the preferred size of the components. Then the list will be a constant size and scrollbars will appear as required.